# "linker' input unused when '-fsyntax-only' is present" on libClang

Tags: c, compiler-errors, clang, libclang

Has anyone experienced this sort of problem while attempting to running a executable generated by clang on a code using libclang (it occurs if I compile using gcc too)? Using few prints I noticed that it occurs on the following function call: `fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", clang_getCString(String));` There is output from the Cstring in this case. I am compiling using Clang -lclang

Thanks.